# Adjusted Kaplan Meier in STATA : stcurve or sts graph adjustfor

Tags: survival, kaplan-meier, curves

I've been asked by a reviewer to plot an adjusted Kaplan Meier graph. I understood that with sts graph and adjustfor, the adjustment was to zero values of all the variables.

So I tried to use stcurve, survival but I'm having a different graph with more steps. Besides, it is called "Cox proportional hazards regression" so I don't really understand if with stcurve, I am really getting an adjusted Kaplan Meier.

What do you think?
Thank you so much in advance!

Javier

Comment: K-M curves are non-parametric representations of the data. You can graph them by group but that's not really "adjustment". (Reviewers are not always precise in their terminology. The will probably be happy with stratified K-M curves.)

Comment: Thanks! I think I will do that!